# ssh on remote server to kill process, pushd script folder and execute the script is not wor

Tags: ssh

I have a requirement to kill remote process of specific patter, pushd the path to startup and execute the script.
I tried so far with

```
pid=$(ssh -q username@virt ps -ef|grep $APP|grep $PORT|awk '{print $2}')

ssh -q username@virt kill -9 $pid
ssh -q username@virt "find /shared/local/path1/app -name "start_app*" -exec grep -nl "9122" {} \;| xargs -0 -I '{}' bash -c 'pushd $(dirname {});bash {};'"
```

When I execute above command kill processing is working fine. The final step to find for scriptfile and execute script by pushing the folder to the path is not working.

For some reason the pushd is not working fine.
The command on the local server do work fie with

```
find /shared/local/path1/app -name "start_app*" -exec grep -nl "9122" {} \;| xarg -0 -I '{}' bash -c 'pushd $(dirname {});bash {};'
```

Please help a more effective solution to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the quotes here:

```
ssh -q username@virt "find /shared/local/path1/app -name "start_app*" -exec grep -nl "9122" {} \;| xargs -0 -I '{}' bash -c 'pushd $(dirname {});bash {};'"
```

Try this in stead:

```
ssh -q username@virt "find /shared/local/path1/app -name 'start_app*' -exec grep -nl '9122' {} \;| xargs -0 -I '{}' bash -c 'pushd \$(dirname {});bash {};'"
```